# No module named 'mxnet' when I am importing in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, mxnet

I am running `import mxnet as mx'. It returns No module named 'mxnet'. I am working in google colab.

`

Answer (score 0):

On CPU, hit this in the first cell of your Colab:

```
! pip install --upgrade mxnet
```

On GPU:

```
! pip install --upgrade mxnet-cu100
```

(more info on MXNet installs [here](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.7.0/get_started/?platform=linux&language=python&processor=gpu&environ=pip&))